# Install Magento 2.1.4 on Wamp Server

Tags: magento2, php-7, localhost, windows, wamp

I wanted to know would I be able to install Magento 2.1.4 on Wamp server? 
If so, where can I get the correct/compatible PHP version for that? 
All the PHP versions available for download are not compatible with Magento CE 2.1.4
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

http://php.net/downloads.php

This should get you going - these are the system requirement for magento 2 and the php download.